# Django - get only year since the date

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Code I'm working with:

```
#models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

#template.html
<span>Age: <small>{{ object.date_of_birth|timesince }}</small></span>
```

That code gives me for example: 25 years, 3 months. What should I do to that field give me only years? (In this case 25) Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Refer this https://momentjs.com/

Comment: you could write a custom template tag which gets rid of the remaining part `timesince(date_time).split(',')[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a function in your class to return only birth year below I have added `get_birth_year` function to return year only.

```
from datetime import datetime

class Profile(models.Model):
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def get_birth_year(self):
        return datetime.now().year - self.date_of_birth.year
```

Now you can access  the get_birth year to get year of birth only in template

```
#template.html
<span>Age: <small>{{ object.get_birth_year }}</small></span>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that function return me valid year in every case, but i think is the best solution right now.